# Sequentially playing audio clips

Tags: java, arrays, audio, listener, clip

Hy, I want to play a string of numbers as an audio track in a java application. I got audio tracks for all numbers (0-9). The input is an array of Strings. Each string contains 1 number. I use a Hashmap to map each string to an audio clip.
All input strings reference a valid audio file. The problem does not concern finding the right tracks. My problem lies with playing them one after the other.

I use a recursive function for this (see the code below). The ClipEndListener has a very simple implementation of the update function and will start the next part once the previous part has finished.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent.Type;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;

public class AuditivePlayer {
    public static final Map<String, AudioInputStream> MULT_SAMPLES = new HashMap<String, AudioInputStream>();
    static {
        try {
            MULT_SAMPLES.put("0", AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Cloud.class.getResource("/sounds/0.wav")));
            MULT_SAMPLES.put("1", AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Cloud.class.getResource("/sounds/1.wav")));
            MULT_SAMPLES.put("2", AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Cloud.class.getResource("/sounds/2.wav")));
            /* ... */
        } catch(Exception e) {
            /* catching exception */
        }
    }

    private String[] parts;
    private int index;
    private Clip currentClip;

    public void playArray(String[] parts) {
        index = 0;
        this.parts = parts;
        playPart();
    }

    private void playPart() {
        if (index == parts.length)
            return;

        try {
            currentClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            currentClip.open(MULT_SAMPLES.get(parts[index]));
            System.out.println("playing part: " + index + " ("+ parts[index] +").");
            index++;
            currentClip.addLineListener(new ClipEndListener());
            currentClip.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ClipEndListener implements LineListener {
        @Override
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == Type.STOP)
                playPart();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems ok to me, and it works for the first array of strings. Unfortunately, when getting new arrays of strings (playArray is called for the second time), it only plays one or two parts, instead of the entire array.
Any suggestions why this could be?

Thanks

Comment: The solution proposed in this thread does not solve my problem. The solution from that thread is more or less the same as my current code. Yet my code has still a problem in it, which is completely different from the problem in that thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (like in the linked answer).

Comment: I changed my code and except for the audio files it should work completely by copy-paste.

Comment: Does it print `playing part: ` for all the parts that it fails to play?

Comment: *"..and except for the audio files"*  Hot-link to two of them, like in the example!  BTW - That code snippet in the edit would not compile without adding imports, so is not an SSCCE of a run-time problem.

Comment: Apperantly sometimes the stop event is not received, even though the clip has ended. And "playing part" appears for most (yet not all). And sometimes the "playing part" appears, yet no audio track can be heard. It all seems so random to me...